# Conjuncts are not identified completely in spaCy?

Tags: python, parsing, dependencies, spacy

I want to identify all the conjuncts by using .conjuncts in spaCy dependency parsing.

But, I found a problem that: not all conjuncts are identified.

For example, in the following sentence template:

`A....B....C.... D....`

If `A` and `D` have `conj` dependency relation; `C` and `D` also have a `conj` relation. But, `A` has no `conj` relation with `B` and `C`; `D` has no `conj` relation with `B` and `C`.

In this case, the `conj` relation between `C` and `D` can be shown in the graphical dependency relation by using `.displacy`, **BUT**, while using the `.conjuncts` to list all conjunct pairs (chunk and conjunct), the conjunct (tuple) of `C` is empty `()`, the conjunct (tuple) of `D` is empty `()`.

Code for getting the conjuncts:

```
prev_end=0
for chunk in doc.noun_chunks:
    span = doc[prev_end: chunk.end]
    conj_ = span.conjuncts
    prev_end = chunk.end
```

**--Does anyone know the reason?**

**--Is it because of the bug in the spaCy library or anything else?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was answered in detail on [the forum](https://github.com/explosion/projects/tree/v3/tutorials/nel_emerson), but the issue here is that you aren't using the noun chunks, you're using divisions of the sentence that include noun chunks.

When you call `.conjuncts` on a span, you get the conjuncts of the span root. In a noun chunk the head noun is the root, but with your spans sometimes verbs are included, so the conjuncts could be conjuncts of that verb, not the noun chunk's head.

Comment: Hi, I have a new question about the type of `conjuncts` , how can I convert it to a `span` or how can  get a `id/index` of it? Thanks a lot!   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68981002/how-to-get-the-span-of-a-conjunct-in-spacy

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68981002/how-to-get-the-span-of-a-conjunct-in-spacy