# How to get the span of a conjunct in spacy?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, conjunctive-normal-form

I use spacy, `token.conjuncts` to get the conjuncts of each token.

However, the return type of the `token.conjuncts` is `tuple`, but I want to get the `span` type, for example:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")

sentence = "I like to eat food at the lunch time, or even at the time between a lunch and a dinner"
doc = nlp(sentence)
for token in doc:
    conj = token.conjuncts
    print(conj)

#output: <class 'tuple'>
```

Does anyone know how to convert this `tuple` into `span` type?

Or maybe how can I directly get the `span` type of the conjuncts?

The reason I need `span` type is, I want to use the `conjuncts (span)` to locate the location this conjunct, for example, this conjunct belongs to which noun chunk or a split (whatever way I use to split them).

Currently, I convert the `tuple` to `str` to iterate all the splits or noun chunks to search whether or not a split/noun chunk contains this `conjunct`.

However, a bug exists, for example, when a `conjunct` (of a token) appears in more than one split/noun chunk, then there will be a problem to locate the exact split which contains that `conjunct`. Because I only consider the `str` but not the `index` or `id` of the `conjunct`. If I can have a `span` of this `conjunct`, then I can locate the exact location of the `conjunct`.

Please feel free to comment, thanks in advance!

Comment: If I understand the docs correctly, you get a tuple of tokens. If you have a token, you can create a span like `doc[token.idx: token.idx+len(token)]`.

Comment: @krisograbek thanks a lot, the problem is, I want to get a span of the "conjunct" (of a token), the "conjunct" itself is in type "tuple".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`token.conjuncts` returns a tuple of tokens. To get a span, call `doc[conj.i: conj.i+1]`

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')


sentence = "I like oranges and apples and lemons."


doc = nlp(sentence)

for token in doc:
    if token.conjuncts:
        conjuncts = token.conjuncts             # tuple of conjuncts
        print("Conjuncts for ", token.text)
        for conj in conjuncts:
            # conj is type of Token
            span = doc[conj.i: conj.i+1]        # Here's span
            print(span.text, type(span))
```

Comment: thanks a lot, a very good idea!  How do you know we can get a span of conjuncts by using "doc[conj.i: conj.i+1]"? thanks!

Comment: From spacy docs. Span is just a slice from a Doc